# Disable current refresh token Google calendar API V3

Tags: refresh, google-calendar-api, token

How can I turn off all the refresh tokens google calendar?

Cumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you wish to revoke an existing refresh token or prevent refresh tokens from being included when you authorize.

To [revoke a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke):

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=<refreshtoken>
```

To [prevent receiving of a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline):

```
access_type=online
```